# Ball impact and distance sensor

Tags: sensor

I am new to electronics, and a professional programmer. I want to develop a sports IoT App and for this app, I need to detect how far a ball hits the ground from the sensor. There can be other stationary or moving obstacles (like a human, a bat etc) that the sensor needs to ignore and just detect and capture a moving ball's impact coordinates on the pitch (ground).

It's kinda baseball ball which means we can't insert or attach anything to it.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is it allowed to put something on the ground? Is it allowed put put something in or on the ball? Is this baseball or softball or just goofing around with a mockup office baseball game yet to invent?

Comment: Adapt some missile targetting code...

Comment: @Janka, Nope there can not be anything attached or inserted in the ball.

Comment: It's kinda an excessively informal spec. | Cameras and video analysis should be possible. | You can buy very low cost doppler RADAR modules that with a line of them should be able to do a good job of ball tracking.  | Better spec may allow better answers.

Comment: What is the maximum distance from the sensor, where will the sensor be placed, and what accuracy is required?

Comment: Golf simulators use two vertical arrays of IR path interrupters to measure velocity and launch angle to compute path relative to distance from launch pad.

Comment: so what solutions are there if we are allowed to insert anything inside the ball?